# How many Praxis points can I expect to get in a playthrough of Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I just got Deus Ex: Human Revolution, and I'm trying to get a sense for how much flexibility I have in spending Praxis points. How many of these can I expect to accumulate in a playthrough of the game? Does this change for different difficulties or for different playstyles? For example, if I invest heavily in hacking, will I get enough of a return to make up some of the points spent?

Comment: not sure about xp reward to make up for points, but you definitely get a lot more loot if you get higher hacking capture augs

Comment: @Yx_: If the additional loot is enough to buy more Praxis Kits than you could normally afford in a playthrough, or is enough so that buying them goes from a hard choice to an easy one, then that information would definitely be valuable in an answer.

Comment: Likewise, increased strength opens up a few options.

Comment: @jprete I have not had any money problems in my stealth/hacking playthrough so far, being able to buy every single praxis kit I come across.  Having not done any other type yet, I can't say for sure if its due to hacking or just me liking to explore every nook and cranny and sell as much as possible

Comment: In case it helps, I'm mostly through the first Hengsha missions, which (I think?) means I'm a little more than halfway through the game, and I've accumulated 21 praxis points so far. However, I'm obsessively exploring and hacking everything I find, so I might be finding more hidden praxis and getting more exprience bonuses than normal.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that Praxis kits can be found as rare loot in a (very) few places. So you can get additional points not just from XP and by purchasing the limited number available from merchants.

Comment: @Andy: That matches my style quite well, so I will probably have similar results.

Comment: I ended the game 10 praxis points short of completely filling the tree, although that was with obsessive hacking and all the sidequests. Unfortunately, I don't know what that translates to in terms of praxis points earned until I go back to the game and tally up the numbers.

Comment: @Darien: That information is exactly what I need, so post that as an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I'm around half way through and I've found around 20.

A good rule of thumb is to always have a couple spare, so if you come across a five story drop that you *have to survive* or a level 5 security device or a wall you want to punch through, you can without having to look for another way or more praxis kits.

Edit: Because of the age of the game we can only estimate, but the general consensus is there are 22 to be found in the world and on a near perfect playthrough of the game 40 can be unlocked through experience. So 62. Just shy of the 68 needed to fill all slots.

Comment: That system has resulted in me having level 5 hacking before I ever get to the second plotline mission. :-) Luckily, I think I've made back about three or four Praxis points' worth in money and experience.

Comment: Another good one is punching through walls, I've found several praxis kits by punching through walls. Paid for itself...

Answer (score 3):

My experience is also that you can fill everything short of 6 upgrades when the game ends.

Hacking generates a huge amount of exp as you play if you are willing to spend time hacking *everything* in sight. I ended the game with about 90 each of stop and nuke viruses, due to my hacking everything and not being willing to use them, in hindsight using nukes on any node with a level 4 or above rating should be fine. It also allows you to explore *everything* in the game more easily.

To help with the exp, also try to stick to pure nonlethal moves, use takedowns whenever possible and headshots with stunguns and tranqs when it is really neccesary. (Of course i did clear that huge crowd of guards coming in after me at of TY Medical with two gas grenades, but that was mostly disinterest in sneak-hunting the whole bunch.)

Augs you can safely skip are the two aim stabilizer augs, the cooldown timer aug, the 
land-quietly aug, the social enhancer aug, the enhanced radar aug, and finally all the hack analyze and hack fortify augs. That's a total of 12 non-useful praxis points you can save on, so on the bright side you can be assured of upgrading everything you want at a pretty early point in the game.

Comment: Note that the social enhancer aug is required for one of the achievements. Also, I found the hack fortify aug to be one of the most useful for hacking.