# In Deus Ex Human Revolution can you keep earned "augs" to start a new game?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Can you replay this game with earned "augs" still attached?

Answer (score 28):

Nope. Deus Ex Human Revolution has no "NewGame+" option. Every playthrough has you starting from scratch.

**UPDATE**: The Director's Cut version of the game *does* include a newgame+ mode.

Comment: Well that sucks...

Comment: I agree with Raven Dreamer, I think it's a good thing that they make you start over from the bottom again every time you start a new game. It's what gives the game the edge of posing a challenge unlike others that let you keep all your upgrades. It would sort of like cheating and pose not as much fun as it should be played. Deus Ex Human Revolution is the one of the best games of 2011. For those who think that it sucks that you can't start a new game with all your upgraded augs, you just want everything handed to you on a silver platter and breeze through the game like it's nothing.

Comment: I think it would be cool to get them on a 2nd play through so you could upgrade ALL your augs not have to choose. (so much for choosing anyway, the game practically pushes which augs you have to have. Game is impossible without hacking)

Comment: @silence I understand what you mean, but to be pedantic, it actually **is** possible to get all the augs in one playthrough.  See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29407/how-many-praxis-points-can-i-earn-in-a-single-playthrough) for more information

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.deusex.com/directorscut), the Director's Cut version for the Wii U will have a NewGame+ option.

Comment: @hammar It does.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst there's no official way of doing it, I wanted to do this as well, so I kept track of which augs I had, and then downloaded a trainer. I used the trainer to give me the exact number of praxis points I needed to re-purchase all my augs, and then started play.

Technically it's cheating, but as there's no multi player for Deus Ex I don't feel bad about it, and it hasn't affected anything on my steam account to date.