# Which missions can I earn the Ghost and/or Smooth Operator bonus on?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm trying to maximize XP earning, and I know there are some missions that at least one of these bonuses are not available. So on which missions can I actually earn these bonuses? Or to put it in another way, how many times is it possible to earn one, or both of these bonuses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credit to **Darth Bieber** on *Trueachievement.com*. (Gh) = Ghost, (SO) = Smooth Operator.

#### Sarif Manufacturing Plant (Milwaukee junction):

1. Entering the plant (Gh)
2. Reaching the server room with the Typhoon (Gh)
3. After having dealt with Zeke (Gh)

#### Detroit 1:

1. Retrieve the Dead Terrorist's Neural Hub (will sometimes work by convincing Wayne Haas to let you in. If you don't and need to infiltrate I suggest going by the sewers it is much easier than the other two access points) (Gh)
2. Locate and shut down the antennae in Derelict Row (Gh)

#### FEMA Camp:

1. Infiltrate the mercenary compound (Gh) (SO)
2. Locate the mercenary leader (Gh) (SO)

#### Hengsha 1

1. Investigate the Penthouse Apartment (Gh)
2. Find and speak with Tong Si Hung (Gh)
3. Escape the Alice Gardens Pods ambush (Gh)

#### Tai Yong Medical

1. Enter TYM's tower by passing through the Pangu (Gh) (SO)
2. Find and view Van Bruggen's recording (Gh) (SO)
3. Confront Zhao in the Penthouse (Gh) (SO)
4. Escape and get to the hangar (Gh) (SO)
5. Open the hangar door (Gh) (SO)

#### Picus

1. Escape the ambush by reaching a lower floor (Gh) (SO)
2. Get to the funicular (Gh) (SO)
3. Summon the funicular (Gh) (SO)
4. Get inside room 802-11 (Gh) (SO)

#### Detroit 2

1. Go to the convention center and obtain Sandoval's location from Taggert (can be done through conversation or sneaking into his backstage room) (Gh) (SO)
2. Find and confront Sandoval (Gh) (SO)

#### Hengsha 2

1. Escape the construction site (Gh) (If you are trying to save Faridah Malik then by all means go right on ahead. It will not affect Foxiest in anyway shape or form. However, if you do decide to take out the soldiers [non-lethally or otherwise], then you cannot get Ghost as someone will see the robot exploding)
2. Find Vasili Sevchenko's GPL device (No ghost nor smooth operator)
3. Rescue Tong's Son (This is a pre-order DLC from Gamestop. If you have it you can get ghost and smooth operator. If you don't have it, it obviously doesn't affect you.)
4. Meet Tong in the Harvester Hideout (No ghost or smooth operator)

#### Seaport

1. Retrieve Tong's package from the shed (Gh) (SO)
2. Place the C4 on the administrator's desk (Gh) (SO) (you will not see these bonuses pop up because it cuts straight to a cutscene. If you're unsure, the way to confirm that the bonuses were awarded is to make a note of your XP before you place the explosive. After the cut-scene ends, you should be 1000XP better off. 500 (Gh) + 250 (SO) + 250 (Getting Things Done))

#### Omega Ranch

1. Disable the signal jammer  (the only way I found to get this smooth operator bonus was to do it in the first building you see once you leave the storage shed you wake up in. If you try and disable it from the tower you will most likely not get it. I didn't receive it the two times I tried on the tower, but I got it the first time I disabled it in the building. This will enable this SO and the search for signs of Megan's team). (Gh) (SO)
2. Search for signs of Megan's team (Gh) (SO) (see above)
3. Find and speak with Nia Colvin (no ghost and no SO)
4. Find and speak with Eric Koss (no Gh and no SO)
5. Find and speak with Declan Faherty (no Gh and no SO)
6. Upload the virus to the security computer and enter the restricted area (Gh) (SO)
7. Use the Leo Shuttle to reach Panchea (Whether you save Malik or not there is no bonuses here so feel free do handle this section as you like)

#### Panchea

1. Get inside the tower and disengage the lockdown (Gh) (SO)
2. Reach the broadcast center (Gh) (SO)

Comment: I thought you could get SO for the morgue retrieval mission...

Comment: THis guide wasn't written by me, so I will have to test it.

Comment: This guide is missing "Ghost" for the Sarif Manufacturing plant - the first mission in-game.

Comment: Cool, at which point do you get it? After you've dealt with Zeke Sanders or before?

Comment: "Summon the funicular (many sites and even the guide will tell you that it is possible to get smooth operator here, it isn't possible. I didn't get it and my achievement still popped. I suggest staying hidden anyways)" It is indeed possible - I did it on first try Ghost and Silent Operator completely possible with killing everyone* - I didn't take out the turret though as not many spare EMPS.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have updated my solution. It's actually really easy to get SO here if you disable all the alarm panels in the area and hack the camera/turret control before summoning the funicular.

Comment: @JamesJiao There's two "Ghost" bonuses for the Sarif Manufacturing plant, one for entering the plant, and one right after you've dealt with Zeke. So you should probably add those :)

Comment: I just did the morgue retrieval mission and got Smooth Operator but not Ghost. Odd.

Comment: Bug note: I played through "Locate the Mercenary Leader" several times with 100% stealth and didn't get Smooth Operator or Ghost. I know what I'm doing; I've played through many times and already got Foxiest of Hounds. On investigation, it seems there's a bug that sometimes causes these awards not to appear. If you're working on Foxiest, you can supposedly still get it, but it's harder to track your progress. See "bugs" here: http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Smooth_Operator

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anyone has a specific list, but to speculate:

- I *suspect* both are only tied only to "main" missions. Programming-wise, the game is probably keeping flag(s) for whether you "failed" somehow (being seen, triggering an alarm, etc) while in a certain geographic area and having a corresponding "active mission" going on. If you reach the next mission-phase without the flags being set, then you get the reward.
- `Smooth Operator` can only be achieved in places where there is an alarm-system of some sort which *can* be triggered. If there is no alarm system, you simply can't get it, no matter how stealthy you are. If I recall correctly, Alice Court Gardens are one example.

---

On a side note, I wouldn't worry too much about maximizing XP. Almost nobody has a playstyle that varies so much that *all* of the augmentations become useful.

Comment: And some augmentations *cough hacking:analyze cough* are complete rubbish and *never* become useful.

Comment: Certainly `Detection Feedback` is superfluous, but `Analyze All Datastores` could have been useful if it didn't require 2 praxis points along the tree. Hmmm... `Last Known Location Marker` never seemed too useful, anything above `Mark and Track 1.0` was more tracking than I really needed, and `Hyper-Oxygenation` upgrades seemed pointless except for running around hubs.